# How can I prevent login box from including background image in modified JupyterHub?

Tags: html, css, custom-controls, jupyterhub

I have deployed JupyterHub and am modifying the appearance. I have modified the login template **(login.html)** to display a background image. The problem is that the login box itself includes the background image.

### Looks like this:

[image]

### Login template code begins:

```
{% extends "page.html" %}

{% block login_widget %}

{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
{% block login %}
<div id="login-main" class="container">
{% if custom_html %}
{{ custom_html | safe }}
{% elif login_service %}
<div class="service-login">
  <a role="button" class='btn btn-jupyter btn-lg' href='{{authenticator_login_url}}'>
    Sign in with {{login_service}}
  </a>
</div>
{% else %}
```

### I insterted the following 6 lines:

```
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url("static/images/login_back.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>
```

### Original template continues (much longer than what's included here):

```
<form action="{{login_url}}?next={{next}}" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="auth-form-header">
    iamdodge
  </div>
  <div class='auth-form-body'>

    <p id='insecure-login-warning' class='hidden'>
    Warning: JupyterHub seems to be served over an unsecured HTTP connection.
    We strongly recommend enabling HTTPS for JupyterHub.
    </p>
```

### Desired result:

Again, my desired result is for the login box itself to **not** contain the background image. Ideally it would be a solid color. As you might guess the intent is to modify the colors of the login box to match the background, but that part I can handle.

Thanks for any advice. I'm happy to edit my question for clarity as needed.

Comment: set the body `z-index` to `1` and then the form `z-index` to `999` then give the form main (`auth-form-body` i think) area a background color, should do?

Comment: @Ylama Thanks!!! That worked. In the style.min.css file I put a `background-color:` on `.auth-from-body` and that did the trick. If you think this deserves a formal answer I will accept it.

Comment: no problem, simple, but ill put an answer so it can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do:**

Give the form main (`auth-form-body` i think) area a background color, should do.

Since as can be seen on you picture the form header `background-color` overwrites the background image, so adding a background color to `.auth-from-body` is what you are missing.

Code:

```css
.auth-form-body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='auth-form-body'>

    <p id='insecure-login-warning' class='hidden'>
    Warning: JupyterHub seems to be served over an unsecured HTTP connection.
    We strongly recommend enabling HTTPS for JupyterHub.
    </p>

    </div>
```